# Calculating brightness of an image in grey scale (32bbparb)

Tags: c#, image, camera, grayscale

everyone. I was trying to calculate the brightness of a laser spot image, the image was originally in green colour as the laser is monochromatic in green colour. but the photo was then converted to grey scale image, using grey scale filter, I tried to define two for- loop to get the pixel value of the picture, but it seems I got something really unexpected, I have not much clue what's going on.  I think I need someone to shed a light for me.

Situation: I have a black and white image, the algorithm below didn't give the brightest point i.e. the white spot, instead it points at some random position ( which is not black nor white).
[image]

EDIT:I use for loop to loop over the picture to find the pixel values.

```
for (int i = xstart; i < xend; i++)
{

    for (int j = ystart; j < yend; j++)
    {
        Color pixelColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(i, j);
        brightness = pixelColor.GetBrightness();
        //brightness = 0.2126 * pixelColor.R + 0.7152 * pixelColor.G + 0.0722 * pixelColor.B;
        //brightness = 0.333 * pixelColor.R + 0.333 * pixelColor.G + (1 - 0.333 * 2) * pixelColor.B;
        brightness_array[k, 0] = i;
        brightness_array[k, 1] = j;
        brightness_array[k, 2] = brightness;
        k++;
    }
        }
```

to find brightness all these algorithms gave a wrong position for the brightest point, i wonder it's because i had an extra alpha channel for transparency which affects the result.

```
        double max_brightness = 0.0;
        int positionX = 0;
        int positionY = 0;
        for (int m = 0; m < k; m++)
        {
            if (brightness_array[m, 2] > max_brightness)
            {
                positionX = Convert.ToInt32(brightness_array[m, 0]);
                positionY = Convert.ToInt32(brightness_array[m, 1]);
                max_brightness = brightness_array[m, 2];
            }
        }
```

The above code is how I found the maximum brightness, I scan the pixel one by one, and set the new max_brightness pixel as max_brightness , so that after you loop over the whole picture, you should get the max_brightness.

Comment: MY code is really long , hence was not posted here

Comment: If your picture is grayscale, all color components (R, G and B) should be equal. This means that whichever of those algorithms you use (or even if you used `brightness = pixelColor.R`) the brightest pixel should be found correctly. I would guess that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Your code may be long but you should include the relevant parts. For example, what are i and j. In what way is it giving the wrong position? How can you tell?

Comment: @DavidG Thank you. I have now included more of the relevant parts.

Comment: What are xstart, xend, ystart and yend, how do you calculate them? What is the result that you are getting?

Comment: xstart is where you start scanning the pixel, x end is where you stop scanning them, ystart is where you start scanning the pixel, yend is where you stop.

Comment: Yes, but how do you work out what they are?

Comment: @DavidG I set the first coordinate, and second coordinate of each element as (X,Y) position of each pixel, third coordinate as Brightness using the alogirthm above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58035/discussion-between-el-psy-congroo-and-davidg).

Comment: The code in updated question seems fine to me. Are you sure you're setting `xstart`, `xend`, `ystart` and `yend` to full image dimensions (`0`, `640`, `0` and `360` for the picture you provided). Try debugging and seeing if for any given `Pixel` `Color.R == Color.G == Color.B`. If you're not using `Alpha` for calculations it should not affect the result, I think. Another thing might be that you're flipping coordinates somewhere earlier in the code and your `X` is really `Y`.

Comment: I'd recommend to use `Bitmap.LockBits` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than `GetPixel`. You can also use `Parallel.ForEach` to parse image lines simultaneously. This will significantly increase your code performance.

Answer (score 1):

The code to work out the brightest point on the image is working fine. The problem is that the picture is displayed in a picture box which scales the image down and your mousemove code to determine where position of the cursor within the picturebox doesn't match the point on the raw image.

Comment: Yes , I moved my mouse cursor to the end of the picture box and got (424,232) but my picture box is (640,360) . I then multipled the e.X and e.Y mouse cooridnate by 1.509433 and 1.5517 respectively to scale it up. Is that what you want me to do? I tried it, it did showed somewhere much closer to the brightest point but not exactly.